# How can I get / set the name of an extruded bone in Python?

Tags: python, armature, bones

I'm auto generating my armature, and after extruding a bone, I'd like set its name. This will help me reference it later, so I can parent other bones to it.

Right now I'm extruding the bone with this:

```
bpy.ops.armature.extrude_move(...)
```

But that action doesn't have an option for the bone name, and now I don't know how to get it. Normally I would get the bone I need by name, like this:

```
bone = bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones['Bone_Name']
```

...but without knowing the name, now I don't know how to get it. I really want to be able to set that name in the script. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can get the last bone and set the name like this:

```
bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones[-1].name = 'name'
```

Which, coming from other languages, looks insane to me, but it works.